# Taking elements from list and putting them in a stack with python

Tags: python, list, stack

This is what i currently have and says that it is missing one argument when it tries to push i

this is the class that I have for this code

```
class ArrayStack:

def __init__(self):
    self._data = []

def __len__(self):
    return len(self._data)

def is_empty(self):
    return len(self._data) == 0

def push(self, a):
    self._data.append(a)

def top(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Empty('Stack is empty')    
    return self._data[-1]

def pop(self):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Empty('Stack is empty')
    return self._data.pop()

def reverselist():
    expression = input("Enter whatever: ")
    stacks = ArrayStack
    listofstuff = []
    for item in expression:
        listofstuff.append(item)
        print(listofstuff)
    for token in listofstuff:
        i = str(token)
        stacks.push(i)
```

Comment: from where are you taking ArrayStack, is it a library?. I've used lists as stacks by using `append`

Comment: class ArrayStack:

  def __init__(self):
    self._data = []

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._data)

  def is_empty(self):
    return len(self._data) == 0

  def push(self, a):
    self._data.append(a)

  def top(self):
    if self.is_empty():
      raise Empty('Stack is empty')
        
    return self._data[-1]
  def pop(self):
    if self.is_empty():
      raise Empty('Stack is empty')
    return self._data.pop()

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `ArrayStack`, not the class itself, change for `ArrayStack()`, this calls the constructor of your class.

```
def reverselist():
    expression = input("Enter whatever: ")
    stacks = ArrayStack()
    listofstuff = []
    for item in expression:
        listofstuff.append(item)
        print(listofstuff)
    for token in listofstuff:
        i = str(token)
        stacks.push(i)
```